# geoclue2: how to get location and configure

Tags: geolocation, geoclue

At the command line, how do I get the current location that `geoclue2` would report?

There's no man page or `bin/` executable in my Arch package.

`redshift` (which uses `geoclue2`) is reporting my location as:

> 7.98 98.37

But google maps gives me:

> 9.749160, 99.975484

Is there any way to configure what sources `geoclue2` uses to get better accuracy?

Most google `geoclue2` searches bring up `redshift` which isn't too helpful :(

Comment: why geoclue2 only and for what use you need it?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I currently use it for `redshift`.  The `geoclue` doco implies that they should be accurate, so I'm trying to work out why it's not.  Also `geoclue` is the only Linux choice for [Mozilla Location Service if not using KDE](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CloudServices/Location/Software)

Comment: For applicational use, I prefer the MaxMind databases/geoIP command/APIs. The API itself seems to be fast enough, I have of people feeding the coordinates in the DB to redis.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Thanks. I'm now using the Google Geolocation API (see my answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To actually answer the question, the geoclue-2.0 Ubuntu package provides a binary at `/usr/lib/geoclue-2.0/demos/where-am-i`, which will print the location GeoClue reports, as well as the accuracy:

```
$ /usr/lib/geoclue-2.0/demos/where-am-i
Client object: /org/freedesktop/GeoClue2/Client/12

New location:
Latitude:    1.234000°
Longitude:   1.234000°
Accuracy:    25000.000000 meters
Timestamp:   Sun 21 Jun 2020 17:54:37 BST (1592758477 seconds since the Epoch)
```

Answer (score 7):

## On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and newer

#### Installation:

```
$ sudo apt install geoclue-2-demo
```

#### Execution:

```
$ /usr/libexec/geoclue-2.0/demos/where-am-i
```

… and see the scary magic unfold.

A `.desktop` launcher file is always required for knowing which application IDs to allow. The `where-am-i.desktop` file is provided at `/usr/share/applications/geoclue-where-am-i.desktop`

Geolocation sources and allowed applications are configured in `/etc/geoclue/geoclue.conf`. Application IDs are mentioned without the `.desktop` file extension.

Answer (score 1):

On Arch, after installing `geoclue` the `geoclue.service` has to be started. For me, accessing the location on Google Maps from within `qutebrowser` worked. Nothing in the config had to be changed. I did have to wait several minutes, restart the browser, and reopen the page though.